# What is the difference between build and patch?

Tags: patch

When developers produce same verison of software, why sometimes they call it "build" and sometimes "patch"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *patch* is usually a file containing the difference between the latest version of the source code and the previous released version. Therefore, it is a text file. On Linux, for example, the command `diff` generates the file, and the command `patch` applies the file (to the previous version to generate the latest version). The mechanism of the patch is used to avoid providing the full source code when the previous version is already available. For example, traditionally the source code of the Linux kernel has been provided as either a big zip archive (containing the whole source code) and also as a small patch file (for people that already had the previous version).

A *build* is the executable built at a certain stage of the project. Often it is automatically built by a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system (e.g., [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) or [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) during the night. In that case, it is also called a [*nightly build*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56490/what-does-nightly-builds-mean).